# Querying Oracle table with XPath/extract returning empty string

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I'm trying to extract values from XML that is similar to below and is stored in an Oracle 10g table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" ...">
    <organizations>
        <organization identifier="***"><item identifier="_745"><item identifier="_9700"><imsss:sequencing><imsss:scoreAndRollup isCompletionRolledUp="false" isMasteryRolledUp="false" isScoreRequired="true" scoreRollupWeight="1.0"/></organization>
    </organizations>
    <resources/>
</manifest>
```

The query I'm trying to use is:

```
select xmltype(t.xml).extract('/manifest/organizations/organization').getStringVal() from BLAxml t
```

The data type of the xml column in the underlying table is CLOB.

Unfortunately, every time I run this query it returns an empty string for the value rather than the contents of this portion of the XML statement.  It doesn't seem to matter what portion of the XML I'm pointing to, it gives me an empty string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: There are no text contents in the XML fragment you provided. What are you actually trying to extract?

Comment: I need to extract the various name value pairs for things like <item identifier='xxx'> and the boolean values like isCompletionRolledUp.  I assumed that if used the xpath above that I would at least get the child nodes of 'organization'.  Is that not the case?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The expression you provided will select the `organization` node and all its children. But by converting it to a string value, the result is an empty string because the tags don't have any content (there are no text nodes in any of the descendants). You might want to extract that in XPath and manipulate the nodes after your retrieve them in another language, or select data in individual attributes.

Comment: Extract returns `XmlType` so you could perform additional `extract()` operations in the context of the result, and you can use `getStringVal()` to retrieve the string contents of attributes.

Comment: I'm not sure I can wrap my head around what you are suggesting since I get an empty string now.  Can you please give me an example?  Thank you.

Comment: XPath returns nodes (which require further processing to extract strings) or strings (convertible to numbers, booleans...) Since your elements *contain no text nodes*, any transformation from node to string will render an empty string. A single XPath expression to extract string data needs to end in a node which contains data. In your case, only attributes do. This `/manifest/organizations/organization/@identifier` extracts the data in the `identifier` attribute, and this `/manifest/organizations/organization/item[2]/@identifier` returns the `identifier` from the second item.

Comment: I'm sorry to be dense.  I appreciate your help.  I understand that I have no text nodes.  I'm struggling with how to write the SQL to extract the attributes.  I've tried "select xmltype(xml).extract('/manifest/organizations/organization/item[2]/@identifier') from blaxml" but it gives me a null string too.  Can you give me an example of simple SELECT statement or help me figure out what I'm misunderstanding?  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that you also have a *default namespace* `xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"`. I will try to provide at least a partial answer, and I'll explain what you can do to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML source has a *default namespace*:

```
xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
```

That means that all *unprefixed* elements in your file are bound to that namespace.

In XPath, elements must be prefixed in order to be part of a namespace. If a default namespace is provided, it depends on your host language to bind it to XPath. You always have two options:

1. Register the namespace (using the tools in your host language)
2. Ignore the namespace (using wildcards instead of element names in XPath)

#### 1. Register the namespace

I am not sure about how you deal with this in PL/SQL, but according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm#1013213) you should probably be able to do something like this:

```
extract('/manifest/organizations/organization/item[2]/@identifier',  
        'xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"')
```

#### 2. Ignore the namespace

Without registering the namespace, you can still extract data if you match all elements and restrict them by matching their *local name*:

```
extract('/*[local-name()="manifest"]/*[local-name()="organizations"]/*[local-name()="organization"]/*[local-name()="item"][2]/@identifier')
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the effort.  Both "select xmltype(xml).extract('/*[local-name()="manifest"]/*[local-name()="organizations"]/*[local-name()="organization"]/*[local-name()="item"][2]/@identifier') from blaxml" and registering the namespace return null strings.

Comment: You can try to debug this with a minimal XPath. Something like `extract(count(/*))` which should return 1.